# Should Laravel migrations be used to alter live column values?

Tags: database, laravel, database-migration

I've always thought of migrations as creating/altering the structure of tables. However, I need to update values in our live database. Is a migration the correct way of doing this -- or should I run my own SQL?

Comment: Maybe seed? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding#writing-seeders

Comment: @rad11 I was thinking that originally - but in the docs, it specifically states seeding is for _test_ data. That's why I thought a migration would be more apt. What do you think?

Comment: seeds are for test or "default" datas and migrations are for structure so from my point of view, you should run your own sql request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrations should only be used for database schema. Seeders should only be used for test data. If you're going to alter the actual contents of the records, you should do that manually, with code, or with your own SQL.

From the Laravel docs:

On seeding https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding:

> Laravel includes a simple method of seeding your database with test data using seed classes.

On migrations https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations:

> Migrations are like version control for your database, allowing your team to easily modify and share the application's database schema.

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's going to be test data, though. I don't think automatic updates to existing rows are inappropriate in some cases. For example, if you made user passwords `nullable`, putting an `UPDATE users SET password=NULL where password=''` would be potentially appropriate in a migration.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit opinion-based, but I'm of the opinion that *some* updates to existing rows are appropriate in migrations. As an example:

```
Schema::table('users', function($table) {
    // make passwords nullable for folks who use SSO
    $table->string('password')->nullable()->change();
});

User::where('password', '')->update(['password' => NULL]);
```

This would be appropriate because the migration requires adjustments to any existing data to fit the new schema. It's part of the migration - a seeder doesn't make sense, and a manual query has the potential to get omitted/forgotten by other devs or in a particular environment.

Answer (score 0):

One Elegant way for seeds is using Laravel Excel - http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs

One example would be this ( in your run function )

```
        Excel::load(database_path('seeds/csv/your_seed_info.csv'), function($reader) {

        // Getting all results
            $results = $reader->get();

            foreach ($results as $item) {
            $comp = Model::create([

                'field1' => $item->field1,
                'field2' => $item->field2,
                    ....
                'fieldn' => $item->fieldn,
            ]);
        }

         });
```

Make sure to put this at the top
`use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;`